# Create a new dataset after selection in Python

Tags: python, csv, random, selection, new-operator

Totally newebie with Python, and I'm trying to learn "on the field".
So basically I managed to open a csv file, pick only the rows that have certain values in specific columns, and then print the rows.

What I'd love to do after this is basically get a random selection of one of the found rows.
I thought to do that by creating a new csv file first, which at this point will only contains the filtered rows, and then randomly select from it.

Any ideas on the simplest way to do that?

Here's the portion of the code so far:

```
import csv
    with open("top2018.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if (row[4] >= "0.8") and (row[6] <= "-4") and (row[12] >= "0.8"):
                print(row[2] + " -", row[1])
```

It will find 2 rows (I checked).

And then, for creating a new csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
            artist = [row[2]]
            name = [row[1]]
            dict = {'artist': artist, 'name': name}
            df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
            df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

But I don't know why with this method, the new csv file has only 1 entry, while I'd want to have all of the found rows in it.

Hope something I wrote make sense!
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing columns and rows, maybe you should rename the variable `row` to `record` so you see better what is happening. Unfortunately, I have to guess as to how the data file could look like...

The `dict` variable (try not to use this name, this is actually a built-in function and you don't want to overwrite it) is creating two columns, "artist", and "name", which seem to have values like `[1.2]`. So, dict (try to print it) could look like `{"artist":[2.0], "name":[3.1]}`, which is a single row, two column entity.

```
artist     name
2.0        3.1
```

Try to get into pandas, use the `df = pd.read_csv()` and `df[df.something > 0.3]` style notation to filter tables, using the csv package is better suited for truly tricky data wrangling.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try asap 

Comment: so I tried but I'm not sure this applies, therefore I'm attaching the result of the creation of the new file, hopefully it'll help my explanation.


https://i.stack.imgur.com/STOTf.png


Basically, it now shows only one entry, while they're two, so it's supposed to have those two...and I need it to have all the entries that have got the right values, based on the conditional.

Comment: In your pandas code snippet you only assign a single value to artist and name, so you only ever get a single row. Try to rename your variables, rows seem to really be columns. And in your first code snip you will need a form of append to create a list (like, artist.append(row...) and name.append(row...)